# Is the intersection of two connected set is connected??

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Is the intersection of two connected set is connected??
I think it is connected, I can't find any counter example to prove it disconnected.
My approach is->
A,B connected.
Let A meet B disconnected,A meet B =PUQ
where P,Q are separated set
What next??

Comment: Intersect an annulus centred at zero with a line through the origin

Comment: Choose $A=\Bbb{S}^1$ and $B=\textrm{X -axis}$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$.Then $A\cap B=\{(-1, 0), (1, 0) \}$

Comment: @GEdgar no, As I know the empty set is trivially connected. So it must not be a counter example

Comment: You are missing the point of that answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EY1xQ.png) is a better Counter example

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.